# Dynamically add form elements with linked jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc

I have a website where a user can configure a list of items before submitting the list.  Each item is represented by a row of cascading comboboxes (each selection updates the possible values in the following comboboxes).

The user can add as many items as they want, configure them, then submit.

To do the add operation, I have a javascript function like this:

```
function newAction() {
    // Get value of index so we can form our ids
    var index = $("#ItemTable").find("#Item").length;

    //copy the table row
    var newItemRow = $("#Item:last-of-type").clone(true);

    // Update all of the ids
    var rowTextBefore = newItemRow.html();
    var rowText = rowTextBefore.replace("[" + index - 1 + "]", "[" + index + "]");
    newItemRow.html(rowText);

    // Append the row to the end of the table
    $("#ItemTable").append(newItemRow);
}
```

This is all working great.

But to enable the cascading comboboxes, there's a bunch of jQuery stuff that gets generated for each row.  It looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#Items[0]_Name').tComboBox({highlightFirst:false,     
        cascadeTo:'Items[0]_Accessories', data:[{...data here...]});
    jQuery('#Items[0]_Accessories').tComboBox({highlightFirst:false, 
    // etc.
}
```

How can I clone this stuff along with the document elements so that my dynamically added rows implement the cascading comboboxes as well?

Comment: Add the same class to every similar element and then use that as the jquery selector. ie: <tr class="row" id="(dynamic id)"></tr> and then $(".row")... also remember that you will need to use the live or on function to ensure that it works for elements added to form after the ready function is executed. This is based on my understanding of your question.

Comment: So I have [0]combobox_1 that cascades to [0]combobox_2.  Adding a row will create [1]combobox_1 that needs to cascade to [1]combobox_2.  Won't marking everything with the same class mean the same action gets executed for every [*]combobox_1?

Comment: does the name that comes after the index change for every level? what i mean is you have given 2 examples `Items[0]_Name` and `Items[0]_Accessories` in this what happens in the 3rd level after `Name` and `Accessories`?

Comment: Yes, there's a `Items[*]_Name` and `Items[*]_Accessories` for every item in the list.

Comment: @chani yes it will, I thought that is what you're trying to achieve. That's why I said that this is based on my understanding of your question. I guess I misunderstood you.